# Do I have to use join table? [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql, join

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Participants (id, name, email, phone, registration_date)
Activities (id, coach_id, player_id, total_time, date)
```

I wanna find all names of players and their emails whose total time ALWAYS more than 60.
Do I have to use 'join' for this case? I can't solve this and stuck with the following code

```
SELECT name, phone
FROM Participants, Activities
WHERE total_time > 60
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you what you want (assuming the 2 tables are related based on `Participants.id = Activities.player_id` relation)

```
SELECT Participants.name
     , Participants.phone
  FROM Participants 
 INNER 
  JOIN Activities
    ON Participants.id = Activities.player_id
 WHERE Activities.total_time > 60
```

Comment: That's great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use join.

How else will MySql know which entry in Activities table correspond to which entry in Participants?

The join part specifies that:

```
SELECT Participants.*
FROM Participants 
INNER JOIN Activities ON Activities.player_id = Participants.id
WHERE Activities.total_time > 60
```

Just for the sake of it, it is solvable without a join:

```
/* BAD CODE, DON'T USE */
SELECT *
FROM Participants 
WHERE (SELECT Max(total_time) FROM Activities where player_id = Participants.Id) > 60
```

But this is inefficient and using a join is the right way to do it.